# Как преобразовать список кортежей в числа?

Tags: python, список

К примеру, дан список с кортежами s = [(1, 2, 1), (1, 1, 2), (2, 1, 1), (1, 2, 1)]. Нужно, чтобы каждый кортеж был преобразован в отдельное число: 121, 112, 211, 121 и помещён в отдельный список

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос ваш код - попытку решить задачу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

еще более самый простой способ

```
res = [int(''.join(map(str,x))) for x in s]
```

```
[123, 231, 312]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
[100*x + 10*y + z for (x, y, z) in s]
```

---

*Объяснение:*

Из каждой кортежи-тройки выберем отдельные цифры `x`, `y` и `z`, представляющие собой *сотни*, *десятки* и *единицы*, и скомбинируем их в одно: ***100x + 10y + z***.

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой способ:

```
s = [(1,2,3), (2,3,1), (3,1,2)]
res = []
for i in s:
    out_str = ''
    for j in range(len(i)):
        out_str += str(i[j])
    res.append(int(out_str))
print(res)
```